# Extract exact matches from array

Tags: r, regex

Assume I have text and I want to extract exact matches. How can I do this efficiently:

```
test_text <- c("[]", "[1234]", "[1234a]", "[v1256a] ghjk kjh", 
               "[othername1256b] kjhgfd hgj",
               "[v1256] ghjk kjh", "[v1256] kjhgfd hgj",
               " text here [name1991] and here",
               "[name1990] this is an explanation",
               "[name1991] this is another explanation",
               "[mäölk1234]")
expected <- c("[v1256a]", "[othername1256b]", "[v1256]", "[v1256]", "[name1991]",
              "[name1990]", "[name1991]", "[mäölk1234]")

# This works:
regmatches(text, regexpr("\\[.*[0-9]{4}.*\\]", text))
```

But I guess something like `"\\[.*[0-9]{4}(?[a-z])]\\]"` would be better but it throws an error

> Error in regexpr("\[.*[0-9]{4}(?[a-z])]\]", text) :    invalid
>   regular expression '[.*[0-9]{4}(?[a-z])]]', reason 'Invalid regexp'

**Only ONE letter should follow the year, but there can be none**, see example. Sorry, I rarly use regexpr...

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\[.*?[0-9]{4}.*?\]` https://regex101.com/r/dU0vl1/1

Comment: What's wrong with the regex you are currently using? You said "it works". And what do you mean by "exact match"? What do you want to match exactly?

Comment: @Thefourthbird citations look [textYYYYx] where x may be missing or a letter a-z. YYYY must be present.

Comment: Then like `\[[a-z]*[0-9]{4}[a-z]?\]`  https://regex101.com/r/vDZ91o/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updated question solution

It seems you want to extract all occurrences of 1+ letters followed with 4 digits and then an optional letter inside square brackets.

Use

```
test_text <- c("[]", "[1234]", "[1234a]", "[v1256a] ghjk kjh", 
           "[othername1256b] kjhgfd hgj",
           "[v1256] ghjk kjh", "[v1256] kjhgfd hgj",
           " text here [name1991] and here",
           "[name1990] this is an explanation",
           "[name1991] this is another explanation",
           "[mäölk1234]")

regmatches(test_text, regexpr("\\[\\p{L}+[0-9]{4}\\p{L}?]", test_text, perl=TRUE))
# => c("[v1256a]", "[othername1256b]", "[v1256]", "[v1256]", "[name1991]",
#      "[name1990]", "[name1991]", "[mäölk1234]")
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/S3llua) online. **NOTE** that you need to use a PCRE regex for this to work, `perl=TRUE` is crucial here.

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\p{L}+` - 1+ any Unicode letters
- `[0-9]{4}` - four ASCII digits
- `\\p{L}?` - an optional any Unicode letter
- `]` - a `]` char.

## Original answer

Use

```
regmatches(test_text, regexpr("\\[[^][]*[0-9]{4}[[:alpha:]]?]", test_text))
```

Or

```
regmatches(test_text, regexpr("\\[[^][]*[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]?]", test_text))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gN15Eg/1) and a [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%5B%5B%5E%5C%5D%5B%5D*%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%3F%5D) graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `[^][]*` - 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]` (**HINT**: if you only expect letters here replace with `[[:alpha:]]*` or `[a-zA-Z]*`)
- `[0-9]{4}` - four digits
- `[[:alpha:]]?` - an optional letter (or `[a-zA-Z]?` will match any ASCII optional letter)
- `]`  - a `]` char

R test:

```
regmatches(test_text, regexpr("\\[[^][]*[0-9]{4}[[:alpha:]]?]", test_text))
## => [1] "[v1256a]"         "[othername1256b]" "[v1256]"          "[v1256]"          "[name1991]"       "[name1990]"       "[name1991]"
```

Comment: You just remembered me, that I also need german "Umlaute". Still fighting :-( See my adapted example and output. But cool explanations...

Comment: For my "real" problem I just used `rmd_text <- read.delim("text.Rmd", fileEncoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` and now everything works - always struggling with encoding.

Comment: Well, it seems you wanted to extract the last occurrence of 1+ letters followed with 4 digits and then an optional letter inside square brackets, is that so?

Comment: Yes, you are right. At first, things are always simpler than they are in the end.

Comment: Sorry, what can I do if I add `"[namex2345] sd [name1233]"` to `test_text`? The first part is ignored. Thanks a lot! But thanks for the great explanations!